# ValueError: Columns must be same length as key in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have df below

```
    Cost,Reve
    0,3
    4,0
    0,0
    10,10
    4,8

len(df['Cost']) = 300

len(df['Reve']) = 300
```

I need to divide `df['Cost'] / df['Reve']`

Below is my code

```
df[['Cost','Reve']] = df[['Cost','Reve']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

I got the error `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`

```
df['C/R'] = df[['Cost']].div(df['Reve'].values, axis=0)
```

I got the error `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas: columns must be same length as key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43523227/pandas-columns-must-be-same-length-as-key)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Problem is duplicated columns names, verify:

```
#generate duplicates
df = pd.concat([df, df], axis=1)
print (df)
  Cost Reve Cost Reve
0    0    3    0    3
1    4    0    4    0
2    0    0    0    0
3   10   10   10   10
4    4    8    4    8

df[['Cost','Reve']] = df[['Cost','Reve']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
print (df)
# ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

You can find this columns names:

```
print (df.columns[df.columns.duplicated(keep=False)])
Index(['Cost', 'Reve', 'Cost', 'Reve'], dtype='object')
```

If same values in columns is possible remove duplicated by:

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated()]
df[['Cost','Reve']] = df[['Cost','Reve']].apply(pd.to_numeric)

#simplify division
df['C/R'] = df['Cost'].div(df['Reve'])
print (df)
   Cost  Reve  C/R
0     0     3  0.0
1     4     0  inf
2     0     0  NaN
3    10    10  1.0
4     4     8  0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, but it did not come from the above two issues. In my case the columns had the same length. What helped me was transforming my Series to a DataFrame with `pd.DataFrame()` and then assigning its values to a new column of my existing df.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the size of data that you are trying to assign to the columns. I had an issue with this:

```
df[['X1','X2', 'X3']] = pd.DataFrame(df.X.tolist(), index= df.index)
```

I was trying to assign values of `X` to 3 columns `X1,X2,X3`, assuming that X has 3 values, but, `X` had 4 values.

So the revised code in my case was

```
df[['X1','X2', 'X3','X4']] = pd.DataFrame(df.X.tolist(), index= df.index)
```